# How to update the LG GT540 Optimus to the lastest stable Android version?

Tags: updates, lg-gt540-optimus

How can I update my LG GT540 Optimus to the latest stable Android? Is if safe to update, or I could *brick* my phone? Or it does it by auto? How are the installed softwares (from Android Market) updated? I have to do manually  or is it done automatically?

Comment: It doesn't look there is (nor will be) an official update. If so, you're only remaining option is a custom ROM. See: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11882/how-to-install-custom-rom-in-lg-gt540

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Backup your phone**

   - this is important if you wish to keep any data from your phone. You will have to restore backed up data (such as apps) after you update. The only way to update to the latest software is to erase your device, so backup whatever you do not want to lose.
2. **Extract the .zip file**, which you can download from [this AndroidForum thread](http://androidforums.com/lg-optimus-gt540/372847-help-me-install-2-3-gt-540-a.html) or [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=927379). Open the folder and install MSXML 4.0 SP3 Parser (msxml.msi).
3. Once that has finished, **install LGAndroidDriver_WHQL_ML_Ver1.0_All_Win7.exe** which are the drivers so your computer will recognize your phone. Windows XP Users download this driver, extract the contents anywhere (e.g. desktop), right-click on the 'android_usb.inf' file and click 'Install'.
4. Next, **open KDZ_FW_UPD.exe**
   (i) Change 'Type' to '3GQCT' **THIS IS A MUST, THE UPDATE WILL NOT WORK OTHERWISE AND YOU MAY BRICK YOUR PHONE**
   (ii) Make sure 'PhoneMode' is set to 'DIAG'
   (iii) Browse for the 'V20B_00+Fastboot.kdz' file.
5. Prepare the phone by enabling USB Debugging by going to Settings>Applications>Development>Enable USB Debugging and connect the phone to the computer via USB cable and wait for the drivers to install for the phone. Sometimes the computer still won't recognize the phone, if this is the case, try this: Windows Vista and Windows 7 users press start and type device manager (Windows XP users right click 'My Computer' and click properties, then click the Hardware tab and click Device Manager) then locate LGE Android Platform Modem, right click it and click disable. Accept any warnings that come up. Also, make sure you've disabled Mass Storage Mode on your phone. To do this, go to Settings>Storage>Enable Mass Storage, and untick the box.
6. Click 'Launch software update' and do not use your computer until the update is complete. The update will take roughly 10-20 mins to complete.

This method was found in the AndroidForums. There is also a [Youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xx-wDHID0ow) on rooting the GT540.

**Bricking is always a possibility when modifying software that doesn't come directly through the intended channels**

That said, the methods here have been proven to work and your risk is significantly less if you perform these steps correctly.

Let us know if you need any help!

Comment: This is the exact same answer you left on [another question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11882/how-to-install-custom-rom-in-lg-gt540). This question, I don't believe, is asking about custom ROMs.

Comment: i just added this answer to that question because it seemed the same question (it has been tagged as a possible duplicate). And i found this answer most appropriate, as i do not believe there is a LG GT540 2.3 update without using a custom ROM.

Comment: see note on other answer.

Comment: While the answer might (ultimately) be the same, I think they're different questions.

Comment: i'll agree with that. i have modified the other post to fit that question better.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need download and install LG tools and drivers from lg web site. And follow the software instructions.

Also this is the site for ireland http://www.lg.com/ie/android/index.jsp, mentioning  Upgrade of GT540 to Android 2.1 Eclair.

You may also check these two references:
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1032744 
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803695

I learned a lot from xda forums and beware most of things in xda are on your responsibility, meaning yes, there is a chance you can brick your phone.

Comment: there is no offical way to update android without the risk bricking it?

Comment: no, you have to wait lg to release an official update. even official update procedures can brick your phone, there is no absolute guarantee