# How To Install Custom ROM In LG GT540?

Tags: custom-roms, rom-flashing

I rooted my LG GT540 now I want to install custom rom but don't know how to do, so I am looking for some easy steps to do this and also share which custom will be best for this device?

Comment: A related question might provide other helpful details: [Install custom ROM from Linux on a LG GT540](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17499/16575)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Backup your phone**

   - this is important if you wish to keep any data from your phone. You will have to restore backed up data (such as apps) after you update. The only way to update to the latest software is to erase your device, so backup whatever you do not want to lose.
2. **Extract the .zip file**, which you can download from [this AndroidForum thread](http://androidforums.com/lg-optimus-gt540/372847-help-me-install-2-3-gt-540-a.html) or [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=927379). Open the folder and install MSXML 4.0 SP3 Parser (msxml.msi).
3. Once that has finished, **install LGAndroidDriver_WHQL_ML_Ver1.0_All_Win7.exe** which are the drivers so your computer will recognize your phone. Windows XP Users download this driver, extract the contents anywhere (e.g. desktop), right-click on the 'android_usb.inf' file and click 'Install'.

Now you have set up your phone to connect to your computer correctly. From here on, it depends on which ROM you wish to install. [This](http://androidclip.com/rooting-and-custom-rom-installation-guide-lg-gt540-508/) is an excellent video tutorial that covers installing custom ROMS and rooting, and as said in the UPDATE, many ROMS with instructions can be found on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=775942).

**Bricking is always a possibility when modifying software that doesn't come directly through the intended channels**

That said, the methods here have been proven to work and your risk is significantly less if you perform these steps correctly.

Let us know if you need any help!

UPDATE: this is a method to install updates to your phone. as far as specific ROMS to install, XDA and google can be very helpful. As soon as you find one you like, go for it :)

Comment: thanks will check and tell you whether I success or not.

Comment: I follow the steps but whenever I do with fastboot -w its hang on *waiting for device*.

Comment: it sounds like the computer cannot recognize your phone, meaning the drivers were probably not properly installed. can you use the device manager to make sure the drivers you downloaded are associated with your phone?

Comment: Now it detects the device using adb command but when I am doing fastboot –w its hang on again *waiting for device*.